# Javascript - Using Anchor to show/hide table from external link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to `Javascript` and I'm working on a project. Thanks to help from a online help website, I'm able to show/hide my table successfully.

When I click the h3 element, it opens up and append the anchor (in this situation, #1, #2, #3) to the URL.

I want to use this anchor element to open up the specific table from an external link from another web page. (e.g. at Home Page, I clicked on this testing.html#1, I want it automatically open the 1st table when I reach the page)

Thank you very much!

JAVASCRIPT

```
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
          }
     });
}
        </script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
        #special1{ display: none }

        h3 {text-align: center;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            clear: both;
            cursor: pointer;        }
            .newboxes {
            display: none;
        }

        a {text-decoration: none;}
                </style>
```

HTML

```
    <a id="myHeader1" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" href="#1"><h3>Table 1</h3></a>
    <table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="10px" class="newboxes" id="newboxes1">
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <a id="myHeader2" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" href="#2"><h3>Table 2</h3></a>
    <table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="10px"  class="newboxes" id="newboxes2">
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <a id="myHeader3" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" href="#3"><h3>Table 3</h3></a>
    <table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="10px"class="newboxes" id="newboxes3">
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. it's a bit difficult to understand what it is that you'd like us to help you do.  Can you expand a bit on what you mean by "I would like it to open up when I visit the website from external link" ... what would the solution be like? also - what have you tried to get it working yourself? please edit your question and put all the relevant code (even if it isn't working).

Comment: omg, sorry I forgot the javascript part! I've updated and thank you! It's confirm working now, sorry I didnt double check before this. Okay, because I have 3 tables shown in the codes above, which when I click the heading, it will append this anchor (#1, #2, #3) to my URL. Because I would like to link it from another web page (E.g. I'm at home page, and I have a hyperlink to testing.html#1. When I press the hyperlink, I want the first table (linked to #1) to open up automatically). Is it possible? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note this only work if you are loading from a html page in the same domain.

JQuery's `.load` function is very versatile. To load the first table from testing.html, we can do:

```
$('#tableContainer').load('testing.html table:eq(0)');
```

2nd table:

```
$('#tableContainer').load('testing.html table:eq(1)');
```

and so on.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3w7Ub/)
Note that the 3 tables in the demo are loaded from [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/pJzy7/show/)

If the URL ends with #1, and you need showonlyone('newboxes1') automatically executed:

```
if (window.location.hash.substr(1) == '1') {
    showonlyone('newboxes1');
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the response! Sorry but how do I get it work? As in where do I put it, I tried putting in the testing.html and try load it from another webpage, no avail. It does not open up the table.

Comment: @glatiuden, `testing.html` contains the tables you want to load. You would use this code in another way with a `div` with id=tableContainer.

Comment: @glatiuden, I added a demo, see if that helps

Comment: thank you very much for the demo! That solved part of my problem! I actually have another problem, now it's linked together and once I open the table it will load. 

Is it possible I can make it such a way that I can automatically open up the table if I access the testing.html#1 from another web page?

Comment: Something like this
http://randomsnippets.com/demo/demo-show-hide-based-on-url.html?option=coke

I access this link and it automatically show me the div containing the id coke. 

Thanks a lot for the response, really appreciate it!

Comment: @glatiuden, what do you mean by `automatically open up the table if I access the testing.html#1 from another web page`?

Comment: Sorry my previous stand was not clear. Because when I press the h3 for first table (which the table href="#1"), the original url (testing.html) became testing.html#1 after I open the table. That's great but if I refresh it or I hyperlinked it, it collapsed when I refresh. I would like the first table remain open if I access it directly from the URL (testing.html#1), is it possible? Something like the demo above, thanks a lot!

Comment: @glatiuden, I see. In that case, just check the value after `#` in the URL like in the updated answer

Comment: thank you very very much! I believe this is what I need, but I can't seems to get it work.. can help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: @glatiuden sorry, I forgot `.hash` in `location.hash.substr(0)`